# Multiple if statements in a lambda function

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to use 3 if statements within a python lambda function. Here is my code:

```
y=lambda symbol: 'X' if symbol==True 'O' if symbol==False else ' '
```

I Have been able to get two if statements to work just fine e.g.

```
x=lambda cake: "Yum" if cake=="chocolate" else "Yuck"
```

Essentially, I want a lambda function to use if statements to return 'X' if the symbol is True, 'O' if it is false, and ' ' otherwise. I'm not even sure if this is even possible, but I haven't been able to find any information on the internet, so I would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: If symbol is a boolean, it can only have two values. What could ever trip the last `else`?

Comment: @ddsnowboard almost anything which is not a boolean.

Comment: @bereal So the idea is that `symbol` could be of any type?

Comment: @bereal is right, I have a list which contains True, False, or None. I want my code to convert None to ' ', so None would trip this else statement. I can understand why you might have found this confusing though, because it does seem like symbol is a Boolean without any context from the rest of my code.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are missing an `else` before `'O'`. [This](http://ideone.com/wjeDnd) works:

```
y = lambda symbol: 'X' if symbol==True else 'O' if symbol==False else ' '
```

However, I think you should stick to [Adam Smith's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33439510/390819). I find that easier to read.

Answer (score 21):

You can use an anonymous dict inside your anonymous function to test for this, using the default value of `dict.get` to symbolize your final "else"

```
y = lambda sym: {False: 'X', True: 'Y'}.get(sym, ' ')
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I ticked w0lf's answer, because it exactly answered my question, but your approach is definitely more pythonic and logical.

Comment: @PM2Ring Whoops, right, because you're testing for equivalence to the value `True` and the value `False`, rather than testing for Truthyness or Falsyness. I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

This is one way where you can try multiple if else in lambda function

Example,

```
largest_num = lambda a,b,c : a if a>b and a>c else b if b>a and b>c else c if c>a and c>b else a
```

`largest_num(3,8,14)` will return `14`