# Dictionary comprehension with elif in Python?

Tags: python

I am creating a dictionaries that need condition inside. So here, I have an `arr_temp` holding some values, and I want to set paired_vals according to element in `arr_temp` (now works only for one case). 
I tried `if` statement, but facing an error that I can't use `elif` inside a comprehension. For now I'm just adding `paired_vals_mass` everywhere, but it's wrong for my situation, because I have several values that complement each element in `arr_temp`.
Can anyone suggest a good way to implement that?

```
report['conditions'][condname] = 
{findings: [{'name': x, 'parameters': paired_vals_mass} for x in arr_temp]}
```

Comment: you can nest if/else statements but will mess your code up

Comment: Can you please show us the code you tried that failed? It is not clear what this condition is, and how you want to employ it in your code  -- as such, a concise answer is not possible.

Comment: you can implement an `if-else` conditional but no `elif` inside a dict-comprehension (or any other comprehension). If you need that, it would be better to drop the dict-comprehension

Comment: @Ev.Kounis so the only way to do it is just avoid dict-comprehension?

Comment: Not the only way, but the cleaner and better way. There is nothing wrong with _good-ol' looping_

Comment: Python lambdas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439434/multiple-if-statements-in-a-lambda-function

Comment: It sounds like you need a function that returns the inner dict, given `x` and also uses an `if-else-elif` .

Comment: @AliceJarmusch Like mentioned, it is possible. In a comprehension, `if ... elif` = `if else (if .... else ....)`

Comment: Please show us some example input and output.

Answer (score 7):

This is how one would implement an `elif` in a comprehension:

```
a = {x: 'negative' if x < 0 else 'positive' if x > 0 else 'zero' for x in range(-2, 2)}
print(a)  # {0: 'zero', 1: 'positive', -1: 'negative', -2: 'negative'}
```

As you can see, there is no `elif` but a nested `if`. Even in this simple case, the code becomes less readable.

A better option would be a *selector* `function` like so:

```
def selector(x):
    if x < 0:
        return 'negative'
    elif x == 0:
        return 'zero'
    else:
        return 'positive'

a = {x: selector(x) for x in range(-2, 2)}
print(a)  # {0: 'zero', 1: 'positive', -1: 'negative', -2: 'negative'}
```

Comment: FWIW, it's probably cleaner to just take that bit out into a function. You don't need a for loop then.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need a function which constructs a dictionary:

```
def construct_dict(x, paired_vals_mass):
    ret = {'name': x}
    if x .... :
        ret['parameters'] = ...
    elif x .... :
        ret['parameters'] = ...
    else:
        ret['parameters'] = ...

    return ret

report['conditions'][condname] = 
    {findings: [construct_dict(x, paired_vals_mass) for x in arr_temp]}
```