# Using Apply in Pandas Lambda functions with multiple if statements

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, lambda, apply

I'm trying to infer a classification according to the size of a person in a dataframe like this one:

```
      Size
1     80000
2     8000000
3     8000000000
...
```

I want it to look like this:

```
      Size        Classification
1     80000       <1m
2     8000000     1-10m
3     8000000000  >1bi
...
```

I understand that the ideal process would be to apply a lambda function like this:

```
df['Classification']=df['Size'].apply(lambda x: "<1m" if x<1000000 else "1-10m" if 1000000<x<10000000 else ...)
```

I checked a few posts regarding multiple ifs in a lambda function, [here is an example link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439434/multiple-if-statements-in-a-lambda-function), but that synthax is not working for me for some reason in a multiple ifs statement, but it was working in a single if condition.

So I tried this "very elegant" solution:

```
df['Classification']=df['Size'].apply(lambda x: "<1m" if x<1000000 else pass)
df['Classification']=df['Size'].apply(lambda x: "1-10m" if 1000000 < x < 10000000 else pass)
df['Classification']=df['Size'].apply(lambda x: "10-50m" if 10000000 < x < 50000000 else pass)
df['Classification']=df['Size'].apply(lambda x: "50-100m" if 50000000 < x < 100000000 else pass)
df['Classification']=df['Size'].apply(lambda x: "100-500m" if 100000000 < x < 500000000 else pass)
df['Classification']=df['Size'].apply(lambda x: "500m-1bi" if 500000000 < x < 1000000000 else pass)
df['Classification']=df['Size'].apply(lambda x: ">1bi" if 1000000000 < x else pass)
```

Works out that "pass" seems not to apply to lambda functions as well:

```
df['Classification']=df['Size'].apply(lambda x: "<1m" if x<1000000 else pass)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any suggestions on the correct synthax for a multiple if statement inside a lambda function in an apply method in Pandas? Either multi-line or single line solutions work for me.

Comment: You can just use a function.

Comment: How would that look like @AntonvBR?

Comment: @abutremutante Write a function to do the work and pass the name as an argument to apply.

Comment: Have you looked at [pd.cut](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) or [categories](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a small example that you can build upon:

Basically, `lambda x: x..` is the short one-liner of a function. What apply really asks for is a function which you can easily recreate yourself.

```
import pandas as pd

# Recreate the dataframe
data = dict(Size=[80000,8000000,800000000])
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create a function that returns desired values
# You only need to check upper bound as the next elif-statement will catch the value
def func(x):
    if x < 1e6:
        return "<1m"
    elif x < 1e7:
        return "1-10m"
    elif x < 5e7:
        return "10-50m"
    else:
        return 'N/A'
    # Add elif statements....

df['Classification'] = df['Size'].apply(func)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
        Size Classification
0      80000            <1m
1    8000000          1-10m
2  800000000            N/A
```

Comment: I tried the approaches listed and find creating your own function is much more flexible and transparent way of doing that could avoid some unintended consequences

Comment: Thank you and Yes that might be the case. However for pure performance something like maxU example should be used!

Answer (score 8):

The apply lambda function actually does the job here, I just wonder what the problem was.... as your syntax looks ok and it works....

```
df1= [80000, 8000000, 8000000000, 800000000000]
df=pd.DataFrame(df1)
df.columns=['size']
df['Classification']=df['size'].apply(lambda x: '<1m' if x<1000000  else '1-10m' if 1000000<x<10000000 else '1bi')
df
```

Output:

[image: table]

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`pd.cut` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
bins = [0, 1000000, 10000000, 50000000, ...]
labels = ['<1m','1-10m','10-50m', ...]

df['Classification'] = pd.cut(df['Size'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Numpy's `searchsorted`

```
labels = np.array(['<1m', '1-10m', '10-50m', '>50m'])
bins = np.array([1E6, 1E7, 5E7])

# Using assign is my preference as it produces a copy of df with new column
df.assign(Classification=labels[bins.searchsorted(df['Size'].values)])
```

If you wanted to produce new column in existing dataframe

```
df['Classification'] = labels[bins.searchsorted(df['Size'].values)]
```

---

**Some Explanation**

From [**Docs:`np.searchsorted`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

> Find indices where elements should be inserted to maintain order.
>
> Find the indices into a sorted array a such that, if the corresponding elements in v were inserted before the indices, the order of a would be preserved.

The `labels` array has a length greater than that of `bins` by one.  Because when something is greater than the maximum value in `bins`, `searchsorted` returns a `-1`.  When we slice `labels` this grabs the last label.

Comment: Great of course +1 but is it really needed to use df.assign here. My opinion is that it is less readable.

Comment: @AntonvBR I love `assign` for many reasons.  First and foremost, because when OP tries my code, they don't automatically clobber their dataframe.  Second, I like the design pattern of producing new dataframes and assigning back to the name better.  That said, I'll show both alternatives (-: