# Iterate through data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, isinstance

My code pulls a dataframe object and I'd like to mask the dataframe.
If a value <= 15 then change value to 1 else change value to 0.

```
import pandas as pd
XTrain = pd.read_excel('C:\\blahblahblah.xlsx')

for each in XTrain:
  if each <= 15:
    each = 1
  else:
    each = 0
```

Im coming from VBA and .NET so I know it's not very pythonic, but it seems super easy to me...
The code hits an error since it iterates through the df header.
So I tried to check for type

```
for each in XTrain:
  if isinstance(each, str) is False:
    if each <= 15:
      each = 1
    else:
      each = 0
```

This time it got to the final header but did not progress into the dataframe.
This makes me think I am not looping through thr dataframe correctly?
Been stumped for hours, could anyone send me a little help?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you look into [How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas) ?

Comment: Thank you, I saw that article and tried iterrow() but it didn't work (plus at the time I thought the issue was with type). I'll revisit this. Thanks.

Comment: np, probably some solutions below will work.

Comment: `itertuples()` will preserve data types, and `iterrows()` won't.  Even better are the non-iteration approaches presented below; docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)

Answer (score 3):

`for each in XTrain` always loops through the column names **only**. That's how Pandas designs it to be.

Pandas allows comparison/ arithmetic operations with numbers directly. So you want:

```
 # le is less than or equal to
 XTrains.le(15).astype(int)

 # same as
 # (XTrain <= 15).astype(int)
```

If you really want to iterate (don't), remember that a dataframe is two dimensional. So something like this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell <= 15:
            # do something
            # cell = 1 might not modify the cell in original dataframe
            # this is a python thing and you will get used to it
        else:
            # do something else
```

Answer (score 2):

**SetUp**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : range(0, 20, 2), 'B' : list(range(10, 19)) + ['a']})
print(df)

    A   B
0   0  10
1   2  11
2   4  12
3   6  13
4   8  14
5  10  15
6  12  16
7  14  17
8  16  18
9  18   a
```

**Solution** : [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)
to avoid problems with str values and [`DataFrame.le`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.le.html)

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).le(15).astype(int)
```

**Output**

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  1  1
4  1  1
5  1  1
6  1  0
7  1  0
8  0  0
9  0  0
```

If you want keep string values:

```
df2 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce'))
new_df = df2.where(lambda x: x.isna(), df2.le(15).astype(int)).fillna(df)
print(new_df)


   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  1  1
4  1  1
5  1  1
6  1  0
7  1  0
8  0  0
9  0  a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [applymap](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-applymap.php#:%7E:text=The%20applymap()%20function%20is,every%20element%20of%20a%20DataFrame.&text=Python%20function%2C%20returns%20a%20single%20value%20from%20a%20single%20value.) to apply the function to each element of the dataframe and [lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33439434/multiple-if-statements-in-a-lambda-function) to write the function.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x if isinstance(each, str) else 1 if x <= 15 else 0)
```